# Design pattern for simple project [Factory vs Prototype]?

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns, software-design

- I am making a script which scrapes many news websites and return
  articles.
- There is a class called `Website` with attributes `name`,
  `url`, and `articles`. Each `Wehsite` subclass has a unique method
  for `get_articles`.
- My goal is to then collect all the articles from
  websites and return a dictionary of type `{name: articles}`. So
  here's what I have so far.

**Specific questions:**

- I believe this is a Factory Pattern problem. Is that the best way to go about this solution?
- Are there any best practices for what `self.name`, `self.url`, and `self.articles` should be for the first `Website` class? I just set them all to a placeholder value as they will all be overwritten.

```
class Website:
  """The parent Website class"""
  def __init__(self):
    self.name = "X"
    self.url =  "X"
    self.articles = "X"
  def get_articles(self):
    return "N/A" 
  def get_all_subclasses(cls):
      all_subclasses = []
      for subclass in cls.__subclasses__():
          all_subclasses.append(subclass)
      return all_subclasses
    
class Website1(Website):
  """Implementation for Website1"""
  def __init__(self):
    self.name = 'Website1'
    self.url = 'www.google.com'
    self.articles = self.get_articles()
  def get_articles(self):
    # insert custom logic to get articles based on url
    articles = ['article 1', 'article 2', 'articl 3']
    return articles

class Website2(Website):
  """Implementation for Website2"""
  def __init__(self):
    self.name = 'Website2'
    self.url = 'www.google.com'
    self.articles = self.get_articles()
  def get_articles(self):
    # insert custom logic to get articles based on url
    articles = ['article 1', 'article 2', 'article 3']
    return articles


site_articles = {}  
websites = Website.get_all_subclasses(Website)
for site in websites:
  site_articles[site().name] = site().articles
```

Answer (score 1):

This is strictly a matter of opinion. Your way depends on Python's ability to enumerate subclasses. I would probably prefer the following solution where there is an abstract base class `Website` that has attributes `name` and `url` and a method `get_articles`, which needs to be overridden. I would then have a class call `ArticleFetcher` that instances of `Website` register themselves with. Then when you call method `get_articles` on `ArtcleFetcher` (this is a class method generator function), it implements this by calling `get_articles` on all the `Website` instances that have been registered (*delegation*). Note: The `get_articles` methods in the `WebSite` subclasses could (should?) be implemented as generator functions also.

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod


class ArticleFetcher:
    websites = []

    @classmethod
    def register_website(cls, website):
        cls.websites.append(website)

    @classmethod
    def get_articles(cls):
        for website in cls.websites:
            for article in website.get_articles():
                yield website.name, article

class Website(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self, name, url):
        self.name = name
        self.url = url
        ArticleFetcher.register_website(self)

    @abstractmethod
    def get_articles(self):
        raise NotImplemented()

class Website1(Website):
    """Implementation for Website1"""
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('Website1', 'www.google.com')

    def get_articles(self):
        # insert custom logic to get articles based on url
        return ['article 1', 'article 2', 'article 3']
        """
        # alternate implementation:
        yield 'article 1'
        yield 'article 2'
        yield 'article 3'
        """

class Website2(Website):
    """Implementation for Website2"""
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('Website2', 'www.microsoft.com')

    def get_articles(self):
        # insert custom logic to get articles based on url
        return ['article 3', 'article 4', 'article 5']

w1 = Website1()
w2 = Website2()
for name, article in ArticleFetcher.get_articles():
    print(name, article)
```

Prints:

```
Website1 article 1
Website1 article 2
Website1 article 3
Website2 article 3
Website2 article 4
Website2 article 5
```

**I think this is cleaner. You get to instantiate just those subclasses, i.e. websites, whose articles you wish to retrieve. So you may have defined 10 subclasses of `Website`, but if you only want to retrieve articles for 4 of them, you only instantiate those 4 instances. Your design does not permit that. If you always want to retrieve articles for all website classes that have been defined, it is a simple matter to create an instance of a website class immediately following the class definition.**